# A Ringing bell when overtiming SO

Tags: feature-request

Could we have a kind of time limit - that could be set by us - that can be spent on SO?

When overflowed, that time limit would have the next SO page display a big **Warning**, something like

> *You spend too much time on your computer and should better go outside (...) or continue your work tasks [for which you are paid]* (...)

The way to count the time would be based on the intervals between page changes - if for instance that interval is less than 20 minutes. When an answer is being responded, the time is counted even if > 20 minutes (thanks to Ajax calls, SO knows that you are responding...).

Just an idea ... before to go outside!

Comment: Huh? Do you also need a reminder of when to go to the toilet?

Comment: Have already this one. Oops, time!

Comment: Please... what is this "outside" you speak of?

Comment: Maybe *outside* is not an Americanism... Outside means outside-the-premises, go and get a fresh bowl of fresh air. Meet friends, etc... Not the *outside* SO to go to *slashdot* for instance :-)

Comment: Install leechblock.

Comment: @Tadeusz A. Kadłubowski (so glad my copy paste works) Can you make an answer out of this advice: you get my +vote immediately.

Comment: @ringO: Belongs on SuperUser, where it has been discussed many times. Check [procrastination] tag.

Comment: How do you keep the fresh air in the bowl?

Comment: @Downvoter - Store Helium or Hydrogen on the top to prevent the heavier fresh air from escaping.  How you keep the H or He from escaping is an exercise left for the reader to solve.

Comment: This is a good idea. I don't care how you other code monkeys feel about the implications. Its just a neat idea even if its not in the best interest of the site and will never be implemented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [cooking timer](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?hl=en&rlz=&q=kitchen+timer&um=1&ie=UTF-8&cid=4870050862681222154&ei=yTXATNikHsWBlAfL64G3Cg&sa=X&oi=product_catalog_result&ct=result&resnum=3&ved=0CEAQ8wIwAg#) can be had for pretty cheap.  You could also use it for other things.

[image: cooking timer]

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what is needed. Bravo.

Comment: @ring0: I was only about half joking.  I use one of these when playing video games.  :)

Comment: Do you mean to keep track of how much time you've spent or to help you with timing?

Comment: @Mark: I use it to limit time spent.  (Using one to help with build times in RTS games is a good idea though.)

Comment: `http://cook-timer.en.softonic.com/`, for those who prefer the software version instead of the IRL version.

Answer (score 9):

**What?!?!?** and ruin the overlord's plans for Q&A Domination? They *feed* off your lost hours! You are going to have to get used to it.

... but don't lie, you like the pain. Shhhh it's ok, they make it that way.

PS: Nobody is really forcing anything on you ;)

Comment: +1 for establishing the obvious *Nobody is really forcing anything on you* while answering a hopeless question ;-)

Answer (score 6):

As I was explaining [in the chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/248194#248194) (posting as an answer helps you, Aiden Bell, progress toward your **Sportsmanship Badge**),

> StackOverflow is a diabolical scheme to turn your free time into money.
>
> But not your money.

Comment: Are you secretely trying to get that same badge?

Comment: @Ring0 Umm, I dunno. How long does it take?

Comment: at least four days, since 100 votes are required and there's a limit of 30/day/user.

Comment: But probably much longer, since you would have to post many ansers and have many later answers to vote for, right? I've sort of forgotten the criteria, even after you and Tim were discussing them.

Answer (score 5):

If using firefox, [Leechblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4476/) is a tool that will do exactly what you need.  I used to use it when I was addicted to SO, and it helped quite a bit.

> LeechBlock is a simple productivity tool designed to block those time-wasting sites that can suck the life out of your working day. All you need to do is specify which sites to block and when to block them.

You have a variety of ways to set it up.

I set mine up so I could browse news sites for up to 30 minutes once in the morning, and once in the afternoon.

I set up another block to allow me to use stackoverflow and a few other forums for up to one hour every four hours.  This was enough that I could use them for productive work, but would get a reminder if I got stuck on one.

You can set up to six sets of websites to block, and each block set can be limited to certain time frames, certain usage limits (time), or a combination (15 minutes if you arrive at work before 9 am, to encourage early arrival, for instance).  It's quite versatile, and I only ever use two block sets, so I doubt many people will use its full capabilities.

Comment: +1 for having read the many comments of this crucial question.